# Reactjs : Data is displaying after manual reload of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a small web application with 2 pages in React Js. I am displaying some list of Cities on my home page which I am fetching from REST API through Axios.

My task is to click on any city and get its name. When I am clicking on any city name, route get changed in the address bar with particular city id added but that component with city name is not displaying. When I reload the page it is showing the name of that particular city and then it is working perfectly fine.

What should I do to make it work properly without any manual page reload?

Following is my code snippet for the issue:

App Component(Route):

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/:city_id" component={SecondTable} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Home Component:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    cities: [],
    name: ""
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get("http://100.124.69.3:8080/api/v1/cities").then(res => {
      this.setState({ cities: res.data });
      console.log(res);
    });
    console.log(this.state.cities);
  }

  render() {
    let postList = this.state.cities.map(city => {
      return (
        <div key={city.id}>
          <p>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Link to={"/" + city.id}>{city.name}</Link>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="align">
        All Facilities (NCAL)
        <div className="Modal1">{postList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

SecondTable Component:(Where I want to display the name of the city)

```
class SecondTable extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [(visible: false), (city: null)]
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    let id = this.props.match.params.city_id;
    await axios
      .get("http://100.124.69.3:8080/api/v1/cities/" + id)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ city: res.data.name });
        console.log(res);
      });
    console.log(this.state.city);
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="align1">{this.state.city}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `BrowserRouter` before the `Link` in your `Home` component.

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate your feedback. It is working now.

Comment: You are welcome. Ok, then let me provide this as an answer then accept it :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks @devserkan

Comment: @devserkan Considering the related issue, now I am getting that particular city name. Now I am clicking on one modal dialog to change the name of the city but again the same thing is occurring as the new name is displaying but after manual page reload. I think my state is not getting updated when I change the city name. As I am new to the react, can you help me out on this?

Comment: Hi. You can ask a new question without hesitating about your problem. Because this is a new issue. Just give every detail there. So, not only me but lots of people can see and suggest an answer there.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I already have raised a new question regarding this problem with the title "Refresh React Component after changing data from a modal dialog box"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BrowserRouter` is used per App. You don't need to use it anywhere else in your code. So, remove the unnecessary `BrowserRouter` from in your `Home` component:

```
<BrowserRouter><Link to = {'/'+city.id}>{city.name}</Link></BrowserRouter></p>
```

Just use like this:

```
<Link to = {'/'+city.id}>{city.name}</Link></p>
```

Also, you don't need to use `async` in your `componentDidMount` method. You are not properly using it. Even you define it is as an `async` method and use `await` there your `render` method does not wait for it to finish the fetch process. Though, you can use `async/await` here not to use the `.then` methods for the promise.

One more thing, do not try to log your state like you do in `componentDidMount` or right after `setState` method. Since it is an async method, you can't get the state value right after you update it. Use either a callback to `setState`:

```
this.setState({foo: "bar"}, () => console.log( this.state ))
```

or try to log your state in the `render` method:

```
render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
        ....
    )
}
```